# Font wont Install correctly in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I am having a problem where I cannot seem to install the 'Gotham' font correctly. The font files are in my fonts folder, but when I try to use them in a program, they are not displaying correctly. From what I can see, even though I am installing 16 different weights, the system is only recognizing 3.

However, when I look in the Fonts Folder, only 3 are recognized.

*Gotham Regular* is actually 'Gotham Book'

*Gotham Italic* is actually 'Gotham BlackItalic'

*Gotham Bold* is correctly recognized.

And in Adobe programs 4 are recognized, and the are not recognized correctly.
In the Fonts Folder, all of them seem to be there. Also I have tried deleting and reinstalling the fonts, but all I get is a duplicate file in the fonts folder.

Here are some images that can help explain the problem I'm having.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It might be useful to include a link to where you downloaded the fonts from.  Someone else might want to try installing them to see if perhaps the font files are bad.

Comment: I got the font files from my work, and I have used them on other systems using Windows 7 64bit without issue. Is there some other way I can see if they are corrupt? I can host my files if that would help.

Comment: If you've used the same files successfully, you've already covered that base.  Is there any other font that's a problem?

Comment: No, this is the only font that I am experiencing issues with.

Comment: Just noticed that these are OTF rather than TTF.  Are any of your other fonts OTF?

Comment: Yes. I have many other functioning .OTF fonts that are working properly.